Did Funapide ever start Phase III of clinical trials?
Funapide is an analgesic that is still under development (to the best of my knowledge) for the treatment of a variety of chronic pain conditions, which include dental and neuropathic pain.
On the Wikipedia page for Funapide, it says that in July 2014, Funapide went into Phase IIb clinical trials. Also, at the bottom, where the different types of analgesics are listed, Funapide is listed as having never started Phase III of clinical trials. I have been doing research to try and confirm whether this is true or if I should edit the page on Wikipedia accordingly.
I have been able to find three different links on this, one of them (from Synapse by patsnap) containing news from August 2022 saying that Xenon Pharmaceuticals remained on track to go into Phase III of clinical trials. (original news source)
The other source (from Xenon Pharmaceuticals' 2020 annual report) mentions that it planned to launch a Phase II clinical trial in 2021, and looking at the 2021 annual report, it mentioned that it was running a trial into 2022 seeing if it was safe when administered as a single dose.
I have not been able to find any other information on it, as it seems that the 2022 and 2023 annual reports do not appear to be findable publicly to the best of my knowledge.
My question is: Is it true that Funapide has never reached Phase III of clinical trials, or if it did, when did it happen?

I only found one trial (on 85 bunionectomy patients) in the US. I didn't search the rest of the Western world, tho. So, in the US, that seems to be true.

Similar results in my searches. I can't find any reference to funapide trials after the 2011 phase II trial. I see no indication they ever happened.

@CrSb0001 Funatide targets the voltage-gated sodium channel Nav1.7.  See this 2023 review of clinical trials of drugs targeting the voltage-gated sodium channels Nav1.7.  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC10166096/  Note that Xenon was acquired by Pacira Biosciences in November 2021.  The 2023 Pacira Biosciences SEC Form 10K does not mention any formulation of funapide as part of its "pipeline."

@DianaPetitti I wasn't trying to figure out what it did or who Xenon was later acquired by. All I was trying to do was confirm whether or not Funapide ever went into Phase III clinical trials.

@Crsb0001 Your post mentioned that 2022 and 2023 Flexion annual reports were not findable.  That is because Flexion ceased to exist in November 2021 when it was acquired by Pacira Biosciences.  The clinical trial history of this molecule is hard to follow because it has been owned by several companies (Xenon, Flexion, Pacira) and licensed for a clinical trial to Teva.  Phase II is the highest phase completed to date.  And no Phase III clinical trials of the molecule in the current (April 2024) Pacira Bioscience "pipeline."
